# NW.JS not working on WebStorm 2017.2.3

Tags: node.js, macos, webstorm, node-webkit, nw.js

**WebStorm is unable to run or debug using the NW.JS tool on OSX**

I have a nw.js project that I would like to run/debug using WebStorm. My project works from the command line, but WebStorm nw.js tool throws an error.

I specified the working directory and the **nw.js** app path. When I try to run it, it says

> Manifest file not found, package.json not exists

The **package.json** file **does** exist and the program works when I run it from the command line.

Can anybody help me figure out why WebStorm can't find the **package.json**? I have attached a screenshot. I have also tried absolute paths, relative paths and placing the project path as an argument to nw.js

[image: WebStorm NW.JS error]

Comment: debugging nw.js v. > 0.12 is not supported:( please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18588 for updates

Comment: thank you lena,
I have started using Electron instead of nw.js and that is working better. https://electron.atom.io